# unable to adjust array input in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a back propagation code implemented in PHP for simple multiplication table. Its training set input is like:

```
$data=array(0=>array(1,1,1),
2=>array(1,3,3),
3=>array(1,4,4));
```

basically it trains neural network for 1*1=1,1*3=3 etc
and then the testing dataset is like:

```
$testData=array(0=>array(1,1));
1=>array(1,3),
2=>array(1,4));
```

and thus the results are predicted...
NOW my problem is I want to change my training data in a way that:

```
$churn=1;
foreach($id as id1){
$data=array($row['count_call']<3,$row['total_cost']>60,$churn)}
```

and similarly wants to change my testing data but this won't work at all...

please help me how to change training data as i want against each customer id, its count of calls and total cost are checked for some values range and then the output will be decided as: customer will churn or not?
my table will be like:
id  count_call  Total_cost
03214567890 2   60
03212999438 4   80

Comment: Hi, 

What is `$data=array($row['count_call'] 3,$row['total_cost']>60,$churn)}
`

Comment: check this foreach($id as id1) i suppose error is here. Use foreach($id as $id1)

Comment: It depends what `$row` is, and `$churn`.

At the moment, it will come back with `boolean, boolean, variable`

Comment: that actually was $id1... mistake isnt here @rahulRaj

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on whim here guessing that your question is related to the loop:

```
foreach($id as id1){
$data=array($row['count_call']<3,$row['total_cost']>60,$churn)}
```

Which will not work and should give you a rather comprehensible error message.

I'm guessing that you want to do something like:

```
foreach($id as $id1){
    $data=array($row['count_call']<3,$row['total_cost']>60,$churn)
}
```

Why you'd do it like that is strange however since you're not using the value `$id1`.

Also note that the `foreach - as` statement is used like this:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).